# Как выполнить последовательность команд в терминале?

Tags: bash, fdisk

У меня есть sh файл,его содержание следующее:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
o
w
```

мне нужно чтобы после команды fdisk буквы o и w вводились сами(пока он определяет o и w как отдельные команды,и выводит ошибку об отсутвии таких команд)можно ли такое сделать,и если можно то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `fdisk` есть брат [sfdisk](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sfdisk.8.html) который лучше приспособлен для исполнения скриптов.

Или можно сделать так (будьте осторожны, скрипт создаст раздел не спрашивая подтверждения):

```
echo -e 'o\nw' | fdisk /dev/sdb
```